# Creating multiple records with one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to get a nested form to work but keep getting the error below:

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ResponsesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: gate_answer

Here are my models... what am I doing wrong?

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gate_id, :gate_answers_attributes
  belongs_to :gate
  has_many :gate_answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gate_answers
end

class GateAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :prospect_id, :gate_question_id, :content, :response_id
  belongs_to :response
end
```

And the DB schema extract:

```
create_table "gate_answers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "prospect_id"
  t.integer  "gate_question_id"
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at",                      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      :null => false
  t.integer  "response_id"
end

create_table "responses", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "gate_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

..and my controllers

```
# responses_controller.rb

def create
  @response = Response.new(params[:response])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @response.save
      format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index', :gate_id => (params[:response][:gate_id]), notice: 'Response was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end


#gate_answers_controller.rb

def create

@gate_answer = GateAnswer.new(params[:gate_answer])

#code below finds URL that user will be redirected to after form is saved
@gate = Gate.find(params[:gate_answer][:gate_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @gate_answer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @gate.content_url, notice: 'Redirecting.' }  #redirect to URL per above
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try Form Object approach from here http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 0):

A way of creating this type of form is shown in detail in the Railscasts [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) & [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). Maybe this will help you?

Comment: Thanks - I have watched that, but I'm still getting the error per above.

Have I done something simple incorrectly? I've even reset the DB and rake:db:migrated again to be sure (and reloaded my dev environment).

Comment: You could try commenting out attr_accessible and see if that works. This should allow the assignment for every attribute and may help you getting to the bottom of the error. Posting your controller's create code might also be helpful!

Comment: Thanks Christian, controller create code added. I commented out attr_accessible in gate_answers and still received the same error. I also did this in the Response class, and the error just added the following: "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: gate_id, gate_answer".

Comment: Assignment in the Controller looks fine to me, model seems to be fine. Any chance you can upload the whole package anywhere (git repo/zip file/whatever)? Would be a lot easier for me, since I'm not a pro.